# Gather or transpose data with multiple rows as 'key' argument

Tags: r, transpose, tidyr

In my mind I want to `tidyr::gather()` gather on not only the column names but also on row 1 and 2. What I want to achieve is to have a data frame with 5 columns and 4 rows.

This is a little piece of the dataset I'm working with:

```
library(tidyverse)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Aanduiding                      `Coolsingel 40 links` `Goudseweg 15 links`
  <chr>                           <chr>                 <chr>               
1 Gebiedsnummer                   1                     2                   
2 Postcode                        3011 AD               3031 XH             
3 Leefbaar Rotterdam              124                   110                 
4 Partij van de Arbeid (P.v.d.A.) 58                    65
```

and its reproducable `dput(df)` to work with:

```
df <- structure(list(Aanduiding = c("Gebiedsnummer", "Postcode", "Leefbaar Rotterdam", 
"Partij van de Arbeid (P.v.d.A.)"), `Coolsingel 40 links` = c("1", 
"3011 AD", "124", "58"), `Goudseweg 15 links` = c("2", "3031 XH", 
"110", "65")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .Names = c("Aanduiding", "Coolsingel 40 links", 
"Goudseweg 15 links"))
```

So wanted out put looks like this:

```
  Aanduiding                      Gebiedsnummer Postcode adres               value
  <chr>                                   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>               <dbl>
1 Leefbaar Rotterdam                       1.00 3011 AD  Coolsingel 40 links 124  
2 Leefbaar Rotterdam                       1.00 3031 XH  Goudseweg 15 links  120  
3 Partij van de Arbeid (P.v.d.A.)          2.00 3011 AD  Coolsingel 40 links  58.0
4 Partij van de Arbeid (P.v.d.A.)          2.00 3031 XH  Goudseweg 15 links   65.0
```

I use the `gather()` function from the `tidyr` package a lot, but this is alway when I only want to gather the column names with a certain value. Now I actually want to gather the column names but also observation on row 1 and 2.

Can I `gather` on multiple key's? Or paste the values in observation 1 and 2 to the column, then `gather()` and then `separate()`?

What's the best tactic here, if possible in a `tidyr` way.

Much appreciated.

Comment: How would the output look like? Please add that in your question.

Comment: I edited my question to show my wanted output.

Comment: @Tdebeus What the criteria/rules divide/arrange your data in explained way? What happened to `124`, `110` `58` etc?

Comment: And in addition, how does your data extend past this sample - are there many more `Aanduiding` with the same number of `adres`?

Comment: I would use a `t` transpose instead of `gather`, but that depends on how you can tell which rows become the columns of which other rows...

Comment: Whoops you're right I edited my desired output again... @MKR

Answer (score 0):

There's two things that need to be done here, and you'll have to figure out how to break down your dataset accordingly.

```
data.frame(t(df[1:2,]))
```

will give you:

```
                               X1       X2
Aanduiding          Gebiedsnummer Postcode
Coolsingel 40 links             1  3011 AD
Goudseweg 15 links              2  3031 XH
```

And

```
tidyr::gather(df[3:4,],key="adres",value="value",  `Coolsingel 40 links`, `Goudseweg 15 links`)
```

will give you:

```
  Aanduiding                      adres               value
  <chr>                           <chr>               <chr>
1 Leefbaar Rotterdam              Coolsingel 40 links 124  
2 Partij van de Arbeid (P.v.d.A.) Coolsingel 40 links 58   
3 Leefbaar Rotterdam              Goudseweg 15 links  110  
4 Partij van de Arbeid (P.v.d.A.) Goudseweg 15 links  65
```

How you go on from there is another problem, possibly a `left_join` based on adres, but that really depends on how the rest of the data is structured.

Comment: Appreciate your answer but those two sets can't be joined because of the column names of the first data frame. Isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of `gather` and `spread` a few times. I do this often when I need to move a value out to serve as a denominator for a calculation.

```r
library(tidyverse)
...
```

The goal is to move `Gebiedsnummer` and `Postcode` out of `Aanduiding`, and to `gather` the other two columns into one column of values. The first `gather` gets you this:

```r
df %>%
  gather(key = address, value = value, -Aanduiding)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   Aanduiding                      address             value  
#>   <chr>                           <chr>               <chr>  
#> 1 Gebiedsnummer                   Coolsingel 40 links 1      
#> 2 Postcode                        Coolsingel 40 links 3011 AD
#> 3 Leefbaar Rotterdam              Coolsingel 40 links 124    
#> 4 Partij van de Arbeid (P.v.d.A.) Coolsingel 40 links 58     
#> 5 Gebiedsnummer                   Goudseweg 15 links  2      
#> 6 Postcode                        Goudseweg 15 links  3031 XH
#> 7 Leefbaar Rotterdam              Goudseweg 15 links  110    
#> 8 Partij van de Arbeid (P.v.d.A.) Goudseweg 15 links  65
```

Using a `spread` after that gets:

```r
df %>%
  gather(key = address, value = value, -Aanduiding) %>%
  spread(key = Aanduiding, value = value)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   address    Gebiedsnummer `Leefbaar Rotter… `Partij van de Arbe… Postcode
#>   <chr>      <chr>         <chr>             <chr>                <chr>   
#> 1 Coolsinge… 1             124               58                   3011 AD 
#> 2 Goudseweg… 2             110               65                   3031 XH
```

Then you want to `gather` again, but to keep `address`, `Gebiedsnummer`, and `Postcode` as their own columns. The `select` is just there to get the columns in order. So all together:

```r
df %>%
  gather(key = address, value = value, -Aanduiding) %>%
  spread(key = Aanduiding, value = value) %>%
  gather(key = Aanduiding, value = value, -Gebiedsnummer, -address, -Postcode) %>%
  select(Aanduiding, Gebiedsnummer, Postcode, address, value) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Gebiedsnummer, value), as.numeric)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   Aanduiding                 Gebiedsnummer Postcode address          value
#>   <chr>                              <dbl> <chr>    <chr>            <dbl>
#> 1 Leefbaar Rotterdam                     1 3011 AD  Coolsingel 40 l…   124
#> 2 Leefbaar Rotterdam                     2 3031 XH  Goudseweg 15 li…   110
#> 3 Partij van de Arbeid (P.v…             1 3011 AD  Coolsingel 40 l…    58
#> 4 Partij van de Arbeid (P.v…             2 3031 XH  Goudseweg 15 li…    65
```

Created on 2018-08-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).